# Drawing nodal lines of wave equation

Tags: drawing

I am new to Mathematica and I want to produce the following figure wich represents the nodal lines of wave equation. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can help yourself. By opening the documentation and reading. Now being serious if you have any code you would like to share that's a great start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {
   {"-", "+"},
   {"+", "-"},
   {"-", "+"}
   };
styled = Map[Style[#, 20] &, data, {2}];

GraphicsGrid[styled, Frame -> All]
```

Since you are new I suppose you might not know about the third argument of `Map`. Try evaluating `Map[g, data, {2}]` to see what it does.

You can create each of the three figures like this and then combine them using `Row`.

Comment: Thanks Pickett. I didn't know about Map command.

Answer (score 3):

There is a demo that generate the actual wave itself with "nodal" lines with 3D view as well. With many other options.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VibrationOfARectangularMembrane/

Comment: This is a comment, not a an answer.

Comment: @Pickett it is not an answer, that is why it is a wiki.

Comment: A community wiki is meant to be a collaborative answer, not a comment.

Comment: It's already not a comment.

Comment: @Taiki "comment" means something that is related to the question but does not answer it.

Comment: In my view, this community wiki answers the question (though to an extent beyond what's asked for).

Comment: @Taiki Please read [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84/731) which is essentially says that the community does not think a link only answer is an answer. Also Nasser has already agreed with me that his link does not directly answer the question; the question is rather whether it is a good precedent or not for this type of answers to exist, and my opinion is that it's not. But it's all fair and good if nobody does anything about it, I'm just expressing my opinion same as anybody else.